# Is it possible to 'trigger' indexing on a site?

Tags: google, sitemap, search-engine-indexing

We're launching a redeveloped site soon. Google has already indexed the site that we're going to replace, but the links that google indexed are no longer applicable, because the new site has a totally new routing scheme. We have new sitemaps for the new site. Is it possible to get google to re-index the new site, or do we have to wait until it gets around to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you've created a sitemap you can register with [Google webmaster tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) if you haven't already, and then submit it. (Site configuration -> sitemaps.) This doesn't guarantee anything, but increases your chances.

Comment: Just this past week, the Webmaster Tools blog also [announced](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/08/submit-urls-to-google-with-fetch-as.html) a couple new/improved ways to submit URLs. Same no guarantees caveat as above, of course.

Answer (score 6):

You should also map older URLs to new ones using 301 redirects.

Comment: Very important. Must use 301 redirects. In my experience, Google will keep trying to index the old site's URL for months or even years unless directed to another valid page.

Answer (score 3):

If you [submit a page to be viewed as Googlebot it will also trigger indexing](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/08/submit-urls-to-google-with-fetch-as.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20blogspot/amDG%20%28Official%20Google%20Webmaster%20Central%20Blog%29).

Answer (score 0):

Another option not yet mentioned is to increase Googlebot's crawl speed through Google Webmaster Tools. This will get your pages indexed more quickly - though of course it won't make the pages rank better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could create new sitemaps with new names that Google is not aware of, and register them in your `robots.txt` or submit them in Google Webmaster Tools. You would surely get the web crawlers attention, which are the gateway to indexing, but you cannot force the indexing of your pages. If web crawlers don't visit your site often, this is a solution.

If you can set a canonical link from old pages to corresponding new pages, that might help too.